# Find text in decompiled jar files with Jetbrains IDES

Tags: java, search, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

I'm with Jetbrains IntelliJ (or Android Studio if you prefer), and my project is built with gradle and some external java libraries from my company namespace. Thing is that is difficult to navigate trough classes as i cannot search text into the .jar files or resolve usages.

Do you have any idea of how to do this?, is there a plugin or something? a trick maybe?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want to access classes inside external libraries?

Comment: I have a script to do this, i.e., to search for text in a set of decompiled .jar's. Let me know and I can provide it or paste it into this question.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA (as of 2017.2 or newer) knows how to decompile JAR files with no source attached, that is when you are in debug mode and you jump into the implementation. However this will not allow you full text search (such as looking for usages).

If it's just 1-2 JARs that you care for browsing, you may manually edit your Module properties in IntelliJ and add the source JAR files (that you need to download from your Library's website along with the binary JARs).

Another option is to use Maven, and have it download the source alongside with the binaries from the public Maven repository (if we're talking about open source libraries).

Yet another option, in an enterprise setting someone typically sets up an Artifactory (for instance https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/ ), which is source for all the libraries and their source code.

If you use some up-to-date build script (for example Gradle), you can build an IntelliJ project with all the sources already linked in.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it. The only way to search for anything in library code is to attach source. The attached source can be code that you decompiled yourself, but IDE won't do it for you (but I think someone can write plugin that decompiles the whole library and attaches the decompiled source). So I guess that could be the "trick" you need to do.

Why is it impossible? I didn't write the IDE so I can't be sure why. But most likely the problem with finding text in jar files with no source attached, is that the text representation depends on the decompiler. There is no "best" way to decompile given class. Sometimes the decompilation may be even impossible (for example bytecode with a lot of goto/conditional jump instructions that don't nicely translate into loop/conditional constructs). In such cases decompilers can do anything from throwing an exception, putting raw bytecode, to just putting goto statements in the java code to at least show what the code is doing.

The only way that would allow to search in decompiled code (assuming you can't just download the code somewhere), would be to decompile it yourself (for example using the fernflower decompile, which is also used by intellij idea) and attach the decompiled source code.

While the above argument doesn't apply when finding usages of methods/fields, it's still not allowed, most likely because the IDE analyzes the source code to find usages, instead of analyzing the bytecode (compiled code).